# I'm facing "Java heap space error" ,when I'm trying to give entire folder as input to Mapreduce Program

Tags: java, hadoop

I'm facing "Java Heap space error",when I'm trying to run the mapreduce program by giving entire folder as input to the MR Job.When I'm giving a single file as input to MR job,I'm facing no error.The job has run successfully.

```
Changes I tried in hadoop-env.sh file:
=====================================
I had increased the memory size from 1024 to 2048MB
export HADOOP_CLIENT_OPTS="-Xmx2048m $HADOOP_CLIENT_OPTS"

Changes in mapred-site.xml:
===========================
<property>
  <name>mapred.child.java.opts</name>
  <value>-Xmx2048m</value>
</property>
```

By making changes in these files also,I'm still facing the "Java heap space error".

Can anyone please suggest me on this issue ...

Comment: There is a way to increase Java heap space. You can search about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can turn on the HPROF profiling for your job with something like this,

`conf.setBoolean("mapred.task.profile", true);`
`conf.set("mapred.task.profile.params", "-agentlib:hprof=cpu=samples," +
             "heap=sites,depth=6,force=n,thread=y,verbose=n,file=%s");`
`conf.set("mapred.task.profile.maps", "0-2");`
`conf.set("mapred.task.profile.reduces", "0-2");`

This will help you to diagnose what exhausted the heap. See more details  in "Hadoop The Definitive Guide" page 178-181."